# How to draw and fill polygons from a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame with R plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, geospatial, polygon

I have a Large SpatialPolygonsDataFrame that I convert into a simple data frame thanks to fortify() in order to plot it with ggplot :

```
Map <- suppressMessages(fortify(CdE_Aff))
Map$id <- factor(Map$id, levels=as.character(0:(length(CdE_Aff$CODE)-1)), labels=CdE_Aff$CODE)
names(Map)[6] <- "CODE"

Map_ens <- left_join(Map, CdE_Aff@data, by="CODE")

p <- ggplot(Map_ens, aes(long, lat, group=group))
p <- (p
      + theme_bw()
      + geom_polygon(aes(fill=LE_EMOS_ECC), color="black",  size=0.3)
      + coord_fixed(ratio=1)
      + guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse=T))          
    )
```

which gives a plot of my polygons, filled with my characteristics "LE_EMOS_ECC" :

[image: result_ggplot]

My aim is to get the exact same figure with plotly.
If I use

```
ggplotly(p)
```

it works well ! But I don't really want to use it as I don't have the flexibilty to change things and parameters from plotly.

[image: results_ggplotly]

But if I try to recreate everything with plotly, it doesn't work...

First try with add_polygons :

```
p <- plot_ly() %>%
          add_polygons(p, data=Map_ens, x=~long, y=~lat, hoverinfo='none',
                       color = I("black"), showlegend=F, hoveron="none")
```

The polygons are not well drawn and they are not considered as "shapes", I cannot fill them with my data (LE_EMOS_ECC).

[image: result_addpolygons]

I also tried to use leaflet and choropleth but it does not correspond to my needs as I don't want a "classical" map of the countries, I only want to plot my own polygons. I think the best is to persist with add_polygons but I don't understand why they are not ordered the same way than in ggplot2. I also tried to directly use the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, to keep the order, but it didn't work with add_polygons.

Does anyone know how to plot my polygons as shapes with plotly, and how to fill them with the data I want to be colored ?

Difficult to produce a "fake" reproducible example with coordinates but the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame can be found here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j49aCvJJmcOzWXm3TYgnXVXVts_GsvwI/view?usp=drivesdk

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `ggplot2` and `plotly` support `sf` objects, those can be used as regular dataframes / tibbles when working with geometry attributes and there's no need to `fortify()`. Even if you have some specific requirements and you'd need to stick with `sp` ( `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` ) for now, you can convert your `Spatial*` objects to `sf` for plotting.

Using example files from `sf` package for reprex.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(plotly, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

# example SpatialPolygonsDataFrame:
nc_sp <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE) |> 
  st_transform("WGS84") |> 
  as_Spatial()

class(nc_sp)
#> [1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
#> attr(,"package")
#> [1] "sp"

# convert to sf:
nc_sf <- st_as_sf(nc_sp)

# first few attributes:
nc_sf[,1:5]
#> Simple feature collection with 100 features and 5 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -84.32377 ymin: 33.88212 xmax: -75.45662 ymax: 36.58973
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> First 10 features:
#>     AREA PERIMETER CNTY_ CNTY_ID        NAME                       geometry
#> 1  0.114     1.442  1825    1825        Ashe MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.47258 3...
#> 2  0.061     1.231  1827    1827   Alleghany MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.23971 3...
#> 3  0.143     1.630  1828    1828       Surry MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.45614 3...
#> 4  0.070     2.968  1831    1831   Currituck MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.00863 3...
#> 5  0.153     2.206  1832    1832 Northampton MULTIPOLYGON (((-77.21736 3...
#> 6  0.097     1.670  1833    1833    Hertford MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.74474 3...
#> 7  0.062     1.547  1834    1834      Camden MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.00863 3...
#> 8  0.091     1.284  1835    1835       Gates MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.56218 3...
#> 9  0.118     1.421  1836    1836      Warren MULTIPOLYGON (((-78.30849 3...
#> 10 0.124     1.428  1837    1837      Stokes MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.02545 3...

# handle it like a regular regular data.frame:
nc_sf$cat <- cut(nc_sf$AREA,3)

# plotly with fs object:
plot_geo(nc_sf, 
         color = ~ cat,  
         stroke = I("black"),
         colors = "viridis",
         alpha = 1,
         hoverinfo = "none" 
         # showlegend = FALSE 
         ) |>
  # disable world map
  layout(geo = list(visible = FALSE))
```

[image]

With tooltips:

```r
plot_ly(
  nc_sf, 
  split = ~ NAME,
  color = ~ cat,
  stroke = I("black"),
  colors = "viridis",
  text = ~paste("</br>", NAME, "</br>", AREA),
  hoveron = "fills",
  hoverinfo = "text",
  showlegend = FALSE
)
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2023-07-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! I indeed managed to do it with my data but it does not display the data when the mouse passes over the polygon, as with ggplotly. If I add "add_marker" I need to specify a longitude and a latitude to display data, and it is not on the entire polygon. Is it possible with plot_geo ?

Comment: @Chika, I added an example with tooltips. Though I must say I can't always explain why and when something in PLotly works or does does not work. For example  plot_ly() and plot_geo() both work with sf objects, yet behave differently.